# Python interpreter not working with imported modules?

Tags: python, django

Ok. So I have a bunch of functions I wrote out in my text editor under functions.py

When I import functions.py into my python interpreter, it tells me that everything I have saved under my functions.py file is not defined.

for example, I have a variable in functions.py called color.

```
color = "Red"
```

When I go to print out color in my interpreter, it says that "color is not defined."

Why is it that my interpreter is not remembering my functions or my variables, even though I was able to import the file?

Comment: How did you import it? Please show the exact code.

Comment: Also, read [this](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm).

Comment: I used: import functions.

Then I tried typing print color, and print functions.color, and neither of those are defined in my interpreter, even though in my functions.py file it is clearly stated that color = "Red"

Comment: You need to show more of functions.py then. If you've just defined color like that on its own, then functions.color should work; if it doesn't, then you haven't defined color at module level inside functions.

Comment: It says: AtributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'color'

Comment: Ok I found the problem. It is because 'color' was inside of a class named 'colors'. The variable 'color' is not universal, so to print it from the class 'colors' I had to type: ***print functions.colors.color*** and finally I got Red.

Answer (score 2):

Did you do it like this?:

```
> cat functions.py 
colors = 'red'
> python          
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from functions import *
>>> colors
'red'
>>>
```

Comment: Why do I have to re-define "color" if it is already inside of my functions.py file and I am importing it?

I already defined it in functions.py but the interpreter is not picking this up.

Comment: Ok I found the problem. It is because 'color' was inside of a class named 'colors'. The variable 'color' is not universal, so to print it from the class 'colors' I had to type: ***print functions.colors.color*** and finally I got Red.

Answer (score 1):

First, lunch the interpreter in the same folder of your script then you have to way to call color

1

```
import functions
print functions.color
```

2

```
from functions import color
print color
```

for both you get printed color value

Comment: So I did step 1.import functions.

Then I type print functions.color and I get this error message: AtributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'color'

***Even though color is clearly defined in my functions.py file and I imported it!***

Comment: Ok I found the problem. It is because 'color' was inside of a class named 'colors'. The variable 'color' is not universal, so to print it from the class 'colors' I had to type: ***print functions.colors.color*** and finally I got Red.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The following code would have worked if 'color' was not inside a class.

```
import functions
print functions.color
```

But because the variable color was inside a class named 'colors' I had to also define 'colors' for the interpreter to pick it up.

```
import functions
print functions.colors.color
Red
```